# How can I install Ubuntu 18.10 on Intel NUC8i5BEH?

Tags: drivers, system-installation, graphics

I've ordered an Intel NUC8i5BEH and hope to be installing Ubuntu 18.10 or possibly Lubuntu 18.10 early next week. The processor is a Core i5 8259U and processor graphics are  Intel® Iris® Plus Graphics 655.  I've seen info from late last year talking about install problems - mostly graphics drivers it seems and providing workarounds.  I'm interested in hearing from anyone that has recently installed to a device like mine.  Did you encounter problems? I've also seen a few that said the install went smoothly, so I'm optimistic that the kernel 4.18 contains all needed for an out of the box problem free install.  Thanks for any heads up you can provide.

Comment: Installed Lubuntu 18.10 today without problem from drivers and no need to update BIOS.  Only difficulty was caused when I changed BIOS settings from UEFI to Legacy and then did not select the legacy boot device.  But after this correction all functions work well out of the box.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. This is a question answer site. Please don't put SOLVED in the question title. You are welcome to answer your own question and accept your answer as the correct one.

Answer (score 1):

Lubuntu 18.10 installed without a problem from the drivers, and there was no need to update the BIOS. The only difficulty was caused when the BIOS settings were changed from UEFI to Legacy and then did not select the legacy boot device, but after this correction all functions worked well out of the box.

The "NUC" stands for Intel's Next Unit of Computing. There are two install options for the Intel NUC: Ubuntu Core or Ubuntu Desktop. Official NUC installation instructions from ubuntu.com are at [Install Ubuntu Desktop on the Intel NUC](https://ubuntu.com/download/iot/intel-nuc-desktop).

Minimum requirements:

- An Intel NUC with BIOS updated to the latest version ([update instructions](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/boards-and-kits/000005850.html))
- 1 USB 2.0 or 3.0 flash drive (4GB minimum for Dawson Canyon NUCs, 2GB for older generations)
- A USB keyboard and a mouse
- A monitor with an HDMI interface
- An HDMI cable
- A network connection with internet access