# Install fails, Ubuntu 18.04 LTS in my Intel NUC 8I5BEH

Tags: system-installation, intel-nuc

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 18.04 LTS in my Intel 'Bean Canyon' [NUC8i5BEH](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/126148/intel-nuc-kit-nuc8i5beh.html) w/ 8GB RAM and a 240 GB WD green SSD M.2 2280. I get this error in the installation first step:

> Couldn't get size 0x800000000000e

When the error occurs the screen is disconnected (HDMI).

How may I troubleshoot this problem?

I've downloaded the ISO from the official site and check it.

Comment: did you verify the ISO was not corrupted by using its checksum, downloaded from http://releases.ubuntu.com/18.04/ and following these instructions? http://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0 Please click [edit] and tell us how you verified the download, or that you used a torrent to get the ISO (which is self-verifying); please do not click Add Comment, instead use [edit].

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I install Ubuntu 18.10 on Intel NUC8i5BEH?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1120701/how-can-i-install-ubuntu-18-10-on-intel-nuc8i5beh) The answer to this question has information about how to troubleshoot Intel NUCs, in particular specific information about connecting a screen to a NUC via HDMI.